# Angular agm map not rendering when using [mapTypeId]

Tags: angular, maps, agm

I have a component which is basically a agm map. It works perfectly showing markers, circles and stuff, but now I am introducing the [mapTypeId] property and it is not working anymore. It shows the markers, but the whole map is not rendering. It seems as when it is loading, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand why it is not working but I found a way that works properly. I used @viewchild from the TypeScript file to set that property there:

```
@ViewChild(AgmMap, { static: true }) mapa!: AgmMap;
```

And then on the ng OnInit I setted the MapTypeId:
`this.mapa.mapTypeId='ROADMAP'`